# AES .Net encryption and iphone decryption

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, soap, encryption

I build a .Net web service which I will consume using iphone. my iphone sends username and password to the server and the server returns if this user has authentication or not. So I want to encrypt the sent username and password through iphone and the server. I am using soap web service using the code shown in this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622376/iOS-Soap-Webservice-Calling-and-Parsing-the-Respon

Now I am confused what to encrypt since i am sending and receiving xml files ! should i encrypt the xml file ? or the field it self !

after search i will use AES encryption/decryption so please notice that the selected method should be good for booth iphone and .Net.

Any help !

Comment: Tip: I would not use symmetric encryption (i.e., AES) in that scenario. Your key will be made public (it will be deployed with your iPhone app), so anyone with access to it will be able to decrypt the username/password. I would use asymmetric encryption instead. The iPhone app would have a public key and your webservice would have a private key. This way, **only** your webservice will be able to decrypt the user's username/password.

Comment: Besides, asymmetric encryption works well on small chunks of data, like a username/password pair.

Comment: good, but what asymmetric encryption algo do you suggest to use?

Comment: Try RSA cryptography: http://www.japf.fr/2013/05/rsa-cryptography-between-a-winrt-and-a-dotnet-app/ In the second part of that article you'll see how to do that in a standard .Net app.